# Application crashed after getting the database file from Android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

While trying to see the contents in my sqlite database file .db, using my Android Device Monitor to get my .db file in the database folder.

I was able to get the .db file, after which my application hasn't been running well again.

I tried uninstalling the apk file and i also tried rebuilding the application, it complains about

> java.lang.NullPointerException: src == null

NOTE: I didn't make any alteration in my code.
I was also trying to get it from my android studio terminal, using the root. Unfortunately for me, i wasn't able to get through that...not until i used the Android Device Monitor.

my error log.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: , PID: 1654
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{/.activity.main}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: src == null
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5111)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: src == null
>                                                                             at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
>                                                                             at
>   .db.CAPKTable.getDataBuffer(CAPKTable.java:140)
>                                                                             at
>   .activity.FuncActivity.loadCAPK(FuncActivity.java:245)
>                                                                             at .activity.main.loadEMVParam(main.java:140)
>                                                                             at .activity.main.onStart(main.java:74)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5111) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596) 
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Don't you want to show us some piece of code?

Comment: the application was working well before actually getting the database file

Comment: Please post complete error log and the code where you suspect the error occurs.

Comment: Have You Reinstall Your application from the device??

Comment: I have reinstalled it several times...i even restored the device back to its factory settings...but, still getting same problem.

Comment: Check whether your launcher activity is properly registered in the Manifest. It will be helpful in tracking the issue if you post some code.